# Mixing Sencha GXT and real JavaScript

Tags: javascript, extjs, gxt

I have a GWT application (with Sencha - but this is a side-comment) and a bunch of existing graph JavaScript libraries.
I would like to embed those graphs within some Java Widget code in GWT.
I cannot find any easy reference to use external JavaScript libraries from within Java GWT code.
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html tells me nothing on how to do the above.

Comment: Please show us what you tried and where you are stuck. This is such a common thing to do I can’t believe you actually tried to do this. Just search for `external js libraries gwt` with your favorite search engine.

Comment: JSNI is indeed the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSNI is the only solution so far.
No straightforward if you js lib is complicated.